# java get accessing class name of static method

Tags: java, methods, static

Is it possible to compute name of class which was used to access static method?

To better understand question:

```
class S {
    public static String method() {
        return "S";// TODO compute class name here
    }
}

class S1 extends S {
}

class S2 extends S {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(S.method()); //should print S
        System.out.println(S1.method()); //should print S1
        System.out.println(S2.method()); //should print S2
    }
}
```

It seems that I can't use neither stacktrace nor type parameter technique.

Thanks

Comment: @DVarga That's an entirely different question.

Comment: There's [getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()), but it won't solve this specific case.

Comment: Do you _really_ want this or do you try to solve a different issue with this? What is your purpose for this feature?

Comment: In reality I have enum S1 and enum S2 and I want to store as much code as possible into interface S. To overcome imperfections of java enums I need to do it. The other solution is to use non-static default method but then I send to method not only class name but also irrelevant enum instance.

Comment: And why do you have two different enums when they are that similar? Maybe it isn't a good idea to use enums if you have trouble with them?

Comment: Yes, but to define 50 objects of the same class with 1 parameter would make it unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, because neither `S1.method` nor `S2.method` exist in bytecode. The only method that is available for invocation is `S.method`. Compiler resolves all three calls to it, and produces identical `invokestatic` byte code for all three calls in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't really make sense - calling method() will print S in each case - because it is the same method being called. Do you want the following?

```
System.out.println(S1.class.getSimpleName());
```

Comment: And how should OP know that it is `S1` and not `S2`? You should add that part in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell.  It is the same method in the same class being invoked, even if you invoke it from a subclass.  An IDE may suggest refactoring your code so all three instances refer to S instead of S1 or S2.

If you want to do anything like this, then consider

```
public static String method(Class<S> c) {
   ....
}
```

and invoke it with

```
   S.method(S2.class)
```

You may consider why you want to do this and if going non-static would be a help to make this easier.